# Can I retract a flag on a deleted post?

Tags: support, feature-request, flagging, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I flagged a GPT answer for moderator attention on June 21st; I don't think I knew about the moderation strike at the time. This answer has since been deleted, but the flag still registers as pending. Can I retract it somehow?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307382/196432

Answer (score 3):

In the network Meta post [Cancel misclicked flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87500), according to this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010) by [Michael Stum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/91/michael-stum) (who is currently a staff member and, I assume, was also when the answer was originally written),

> You also cannot retract an active flag for moderator attention if the post has been deleted and you don't have enough rep to see deleted posts.

This answer was posted just over $7$ years ago (on July $7$, $2016$), but I believe its information should still be current. Also, as can be seen in the [answer's revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/281010/revisions), that particular sentence was actually added by [Sonic the Anonymous Hedgehog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/377214/sonic-the-anonymous-hedgehog) in Revision #$9$ on Feb. $26$, $2018$. Nonetheless, I assume Michael accepts this change as it's not been changed or reversed, and also Sonic is the member who seems to have been the most involved in originally creating the set of Meta FAQ posts, and is from what I've seen also the one who does the most to keep them current. Thus, I assume we can trust this sentence even though Michael didn't write it.

However, note that a link in the [Allow retracting a moderator flag if the post has been deleted and I don't have enough reputation to see deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307382) post (given in [Martin R's comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35904/can-i-retract-a-flag-on-a-deleted-post#comment169409_35904)) is to the Meta SO post [Allow retracting flags on deleted posts even if you can't view deleted posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333954). An [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399516) there by [Samuel Liew](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/584192/samuel-liew) (a current SO diamond moderator) says

> As the userscript in [Michał Perłakowski's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333960) is no longer available, I have written my own version which can be found here: [FlagRetractor](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/FlagRetractor.user.js)

Comment: Referring to the FlagRetractor link: I've never run outside code to modify something on SE, is there a link that explains how this works, and how to run it?

Comment: @DavidRaveh I also have never yet run any SE userscript. As for there being a link regarding the way FlagRetractor works and how to run it, I'm don't know of any. Nonetheless, there's the network Meta post [how do I run a userscript?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49800), but its from over $13$ years ago, and there are not many details in the one answer there. Also, you may wish to check the [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) SE site as its description says "Stack Apps is a question and answer site for apps, scripts, and development with the Stack Exchange API".